# Remove Addresses tab from customer edit page magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, tabs, address

How to remove Addresses tab from customer edit(form) page in **admin panel** Magento 2?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: What I have tried so far is removing address fieldset in customer_form.xml and unlinking js/edit/tab/addresses.js

Answer (score 0):

Create `customer_account.xml` if does not exit at `app/design/frontend/{ThemeVendorName}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Customer/layout/`

and inside it adds below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-address-link" remove="true" />

    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I want to remove it in the admin panel, not in the frontend. Let me edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're still there to accept my answer.
Unlike the others that could be removed by xml, build a plugin instead.

etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Form\AddressFieldset">
    <plugin name="long_customer_customer_address" type="Long\Customer\Plugin\Ui\Component\Form\AddressFieldset" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Plugin file

```
<?php

namespace Long\Customer\Plugin\Ui\Component\Form;

use Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Form\AddressFieldset as AddressFieldsetParent;

class AddressFieldset
{
    /**
     * @param AddressFieldsetParent $subject
     * @param $result
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterIsComponentVisible(AddressFieldsetParent $subject, $result){
        $result = false;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

app/code/[Vendor]/[MODULE]/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml

> Remove orders tab from admin customer edit

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="orders" remove="true" />
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can override below file and remove whole **fieldset="address"** tag or you can comment it.

File path.

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml

You can create your custom file in below directory path

> YourVendorName/YourModuleName/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml

remove or comment **fieldset="address"**

Please up vote if it is helpful for you.

Comment: Tried it, It only removes the form inside the tab, not the tab.

Comment: You must have to remove whole fieldset tag not only single line.